# After deploying nginx ingress controller to my EKS cluster, why is my connection timing out when I visit my ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I'm currently in the process of deploying nginx ingress controller and switching over our currently deployed kubernetes ingress resources to use it. I've installed the ingress controller using helm. I've installed chart version 4.8.3, only modifying a couple values for debugging purposes. We're running k8s version 1.24.

My ingress controller pod is running fine. Upon ingress creation, an aws load balancer is created and assigned to the ingress's address. In EC2 console, I can verify that the load balancer has a target group to route https traffic to, which is utilizing my certificate. I have also verified that the security groups associated with my newly created load balancer have no restrictions.

Here are the annotations I've added to my ingress nginx controller service:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-path: /
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <CERT>
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

Here are the annotations I've added to my ingress resource:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 30s
nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 20s
```

When I visit my ingress in my web browser, the page eventually responds with the `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error message. What error did I make in my setup which is preventing traffic from being routed to my backend service?

I've validated that my ingress controller pod is running. Upon ingress creation, I validated in my nginx logs that it is detecting the ingress with the proper ingressClass. If I describe my ingress resource, it seems to be stuck at "Scheduled for sync" event and never changes. I have also confirmed that there are no duplicate ingress resources with the same hostname being set. `dig` and `nslookup` properly resolve my ingress hostname. I've also validated that if I port-forward my nginx ingress controller service, I can reach the backend service login page with a `curl 127.0.0.1:8080 -H "Host: <ingress>". I've also set the ExternalTrafficPolicy as` local` while troubleshooting.

When I visit my ingress in my web browser, which is Grafana in this case, I want to be able to load the service and use it.

Comment: Doesn't sound like your NLB is internet-facing.

Comment: Try tearing it down and adding the following annotation: `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internet-facing"`. [Source](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/guide/service/annotations/#lb-scheme)